# how to specify the index of text to be matched in xpath query

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing

I have a xml file [xml](http://pastebin.com/YgpZJhHC) and i need to parse it. What i want to do is to get the last position of tag script based on the previous input.

my previous input will be the 2nd position of the tag script (say - networkSecurity, sdnSTC)

so how can I specify the index of the text to be matched in the xquery.

the code that I am using now is -

```
   <?php

    $variable=$_POST['module']; 
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
            $xmldoc->load('info.xml');

            $xpathvar = new Domxpath($xmldoc);

    $queryResult = $xpathvar->query("testcase[contains(script,'$variable')]"); 

            foreach($queryResult as $result)
            {
                    echo $result->textContent;
            }

    ?>
```

here in this $queryResult how I can specify that the index of the $variable is 2 ?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Match a substring of the text in a `script` element? Match after the second `/`?

Comment: @nwellnhof - I want to match the value of $variable in the the script tag and i want to specify in the query that $variable should appear in the 2nd position of script tag.

Comment: But what do you mean by "2nd position"? After the second character? After the second `/`?

Comment: my script tag looks like 

`<script>scripts/testSuite/sdnSTC/Flare/Backup_Restore/Sprint16_tests/Backup_Restore_RestoreModeOnNORestoreFile.tcl</script>`

so by 2nd position I mean that my query should match $varibale with the "sdnSTC" (in this case) which is the 2nd position of the script tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that by "2nd position" you mean the third component of the path in a `script` element. Since with PHP you're limited to XPath 1.0, I think it would be easier to simply extract all `testcase` elements and see if they match with PHP code (using `explode`, for example). But you could also use an XPath expression with the `substring-after` function:

```
testcase[
    substring-after(
        substring-after(script, '/'),
        '/'
    ) = '$variable' or
    substring-before(
        substring-after(
            substring-after(script, '/'),
            '/'
        ),
        '/'
    ) = '$variable'
]
```

Also note that you seem to insert an unchecked HTTP POST parameter into your XPath expression. This is a security problem similar to SQL injection.

Comment: hey it works !!

My only worry is how to fetch the testcase name (ends with .tcl in script tag) in my output ?